# Firebase getUser(uid) connection refused error

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

My firebase login was working absolutely fine almost 24 hours ago. Now I am getting a strange error while calling the firebase auth getUser function.

```
$auth = app('firebase.auth');
$token = $auth->verifyIdToken($data['token']);
$uid = $token->getClaim('sub');
/** @var Auth\UserRecord $ur */
$ur = $auth->getUser($uid);
```

Error occurs on last line of the code, which is **$auth->getUser($uid)**. Exact error log is below

```
[2022-02-12 22:05:05] production.ERROR: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to oauth2.googleapis.com port 443: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) {"exception":"[object] (Kreait\\Firebase\\Exception\\Auth\\AuthError(code: 0): cURL error 7: Failed to connect to oauth2.googleapis.com port 443: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) at /mnt/d/Fundashots/server/vendor/kreait/firebase-php/src/Firebase/Exception/AuthApiExceptionConverter.php:134)
[stacktrace]
#0 /mnt/d/Fundashots/server/vendor/kreait/firebase-php/src/Firebase/Exception/AuthApiExceptionConverter.php(50): Kreait\\Firebase\\Exception\\AuthApiExceptionConverter->convertGuzzleRequestException(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ConnectException))
#1 /mnt/d/Fundashots/server/vendor/kreait/firebase-php/src/Firebase/Auth/ApiClient.php(221): Kreait\\Firebase\\Exception\\AuthApiExceptionConverter->convertException(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ConnectException))
#2 /mnt/d/Fundashots/server/vendor/kreait/firebase-php/src/Firebase/Auth/ApiClient.php(140): Kreait\\Firebase\\Auth\\ApiClient->requestApi('getAccountInfo', Array)
#3 /mnt/d/Fundashots/server/vendor/kreait/firebase-php/src/Firebase/Auth.php(106): Kreait\\Firebase\\Auth\\ApiClient->getAccountInfo(Array)
#4 /mnt/d/Fundashots/server/vendor/kreait/firebase-php/src/Firebase/Auth.php(87): Kreait\\Firebase\\Auth->getUsers(Array)
#5 /mnt/d/Fundashots/server/app/Http/Controllers/LoginController.php(82): Kreait\\Firebase\\Auth->getUser('Ez5kr2L8EFaHeWJ...')
```

It seems Google is refusing API calls to get User details, but I can't understand why and how to fix it. Currently, I am using below-mentioned dependencies

```
"kreait/laravel-firebase":"2.4.0"
"kreait/firebase-tokens":"1.15.0"
"kreait/firebase-php":"5.19.0"
```

When I try to ping **oauth2.googleapis.com**, it says

```
Pinging dotblocking.dummy [13.127.247.216] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
```

Comment: Your ISP is blocking oauth2.googleapis.com. I am facing the same issue. Are you on Airtel?

Comment: Chenging your DNS to 8.8.8.8 might fix this issue.